# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate: Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, messageui

I tried to implement MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate to use `mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)` method but get the error:

***Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'SettingsViewModel' should inherit 'NSObject' instead***

What could be the problem?

Here is the code:

```
extension SettingsViewModel: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear enough. You need to have `SettingsViewModel` extend `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

[The `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerdelegate) extends [the `NSObjectProtocol` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol). You are only allowed to conform to `NSObjectProtocol` by subclassing the `NSObject` class.

You need to find the declaration of `SettingsViewModel` in your source code and change it to extend `NSObject`:

```
class SettingsViewModel: NSObject {
   ...
```